# Why does calling the + operator on a null event reference initialize an event?

Tags: c#

Am I missing something here? How are null Event references changed by an operator?

```
class Foo
{

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> anEvent;
    public Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(anEvent == null); // true
        anEvent += (sender, args) => { var i = 0; };
    }

    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        var a = new Foo();
        Console.WriteLine(a.anEvent == null); // false
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}
```

Comment: it's magic that involves adding delegates to the event and overridden operators. Have you read up on what is behind an event exactly?

Comment: An operator is not an instance method though. Look at the signatures when you override them -- it's static.

Comment: += for delegates actually call an `add` or `remove` (for -=) method, they are not operators in the traditional sense.

Comment: @JosephNields No operators are ever "instance", so no, it's *not* an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This actually runs through some compiler changes to your code. When you compile this, it creates a wrappers around `anEvent` for adding/removing handlers, very similarly to the way properties work. For example, in your class, when compiled, you would see (more or less):

```
class Foo
{
    private EventHandler<EventArgs> anEvent;

    public void add_anEvent(EventHandler<EventArgs> delegateToAdd)
    {
        //some code to make this safe, but basically calls-ish:
        anEvent = System.Delegate.Combine(anEvent, delegateToAdd);
    }

    public Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(anEvent == null); // true

        //your += operator is converted to a call to "add_Event" instead
        add_anEvent((sender, args) => { var i = 0; };);
    }
}
```

Although an oversimplification of the underlying threadsafe code, this demonstrates how the `null` case is handled via the [`System.Delegate.Combine` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30cyx32c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which returns:

> A new delegate with an invocation list that concatenates the
>   invocation lists of *a* and *b* in that order. Returns *a* if *b* is **null**,
>   returns *b* if *a* is a null reference, and returns a null reference if
>   both *a* and *b* are null references.

EDIT: You can read up on the `add` and `remove` event accessors here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664456%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

This page is about implementing custom event accessors, but a perhaps relevant passage on that page might be:

> Each add-accessor-declaration and remove-accessor-declaration
>   corresponds to a method with a single value parameter of the event
>   type and a void return type. The implicit parameter of an event
>   accessor is named value. When an event is used in an event assignment,
>   the appropriate event accessor is used. Specifically, if the
>   assignment operator is += then the add accessor is used, and if the
>   assignment operator is -= then the remove accessor is used.

Even when you don't provide custom `add` and `remove` implementations, the compiler fills a basic one out for you. (Just like if you have blank `get` and `set` properties, the compiler fills a basic one out) In this sense, the "null" case is handled for you by calling these methods; you don't *directly* operate on the `null` event field.

Comment: @JosephNields: You're welcome! Right now I just found another StackOverflow question/answer that has more in depth information about this and the exact C#-equivalent code that I glossed over (with the "some code to make this safe, but basically calls-ish"). Feel free to read it and the linked blogged entries. Great learning! http://stackoverflow.com/q/15646155/1269654